# MS Access (ADODB connection) slow on .Close()

Tags: powershell, adodb

Newb Question: I'm working on a PowerShell script that will store it's "working data" in a local MS Access database file using the method outlined [in this blog post.](http://www.joseph-streeter.com/?p=914)

Everything seems to be functioning, but when adding around 500 records to the database file, the subsequent $connection.Close() command takes in excess of 20 seconds to complete.

Is this normal?  Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** - Relevant code below:

```
# setup & open the internal database
$dbCursor = 3
$dbLock = 3
$connection = New-Object -com "ADODB.Connection"
$connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=$PSScriptRoot\masterdb.accdb;Persist Security Info=True;"
$recordSet = New-Object -com "ADODB.Recordset"
$connection.Open($connectionString)
$recordSet.Open("SELECT * FROM STUDENTS", $connection, $dbCursor, $dbLock)

# presence check arrays
$dbArray = @()

# import the CSV file
$csvFile = Import-Csv -path "$PSScriptRoot\$cognosDownload"

# populate dbArray from database
$recordSet.MoveFirst()
do {
    $dbArray += $recordSet.Fields.Item("SID").Value;
    $recordSet.MoveNext()
} until ($recordSet.EOF -eq $True)

# add new records from CSV to database file
foreach($csvLine in $csvFile)
{
    # if CSV record is for a new student, add student to database.
    if ($dbArray -notcontains $csvLine.SID)
    {
        $recordSet.AddNew()
        $recordSet.Fields.Item("SID").value = $csvLine.SID
        $recordSet.Fields.Item("lastName").value = $csvLine.lastName
        $recordSet.Fields.Item("firstName").value = $csvLine.firstName
        $recordSet.Fields.Item("grade").value = $csvLine.grade
        $recordSet.Fields.Item("username").value = Format-Username $csvLine.firstName $csvLine.lastName
        $recordSet.Fields.Item("password").value = New-Password
        $recordSet.Fields.Item("status").value = "A"
        $recordSet.Update()
    }
}

# remove (rather large) arrays from memory
Remove-Variable dbArray

#close it all up
$recordSet.Close()
$connection.Close()
```

Comment: You're not flushing the buffer to the file until the `.Close()` is made. So that 20 seconds is how long it takes the access engine to appropriately layout the records and write them to the file. Even here, 20 seconds seems excessive, though. There may be something else going on you haven't told us about, hence this is only a comment, not an answer. If it's simple data, you may be better off just using CSV. Powershell is _good_ at reading and writing CSV data.

Comment: Thank you.  It is fairly simple data, and I have been considering switching to a CSV file... I've just been a little worried about data integrity.  (How likely is it that the CSV file would become corrupted?)

Comment: No more likely than for an access db.

Comment: Please post the actual code you use not just the link of borrowed code. Where does your source data derive? Are you looping to append records into Access database?

Comment: Just edited my original post to include the relevant code.  Source data is a local CSV file which is imported to a local .ACCDB file.  I am indeed looping through the CSV and appending to the database.